# Oracle ARCXXXX.0001 files and how to clear them

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle12c

I would like to know what these files are and how to clear them.
They've been using up quite a bit of my disk space.

[ARC file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kygzH.png)

I have tried using RMAN to try and clear but I will get this error:

[RMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqA2p.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the text of your commands and output in the problem; do not post screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current system is not critical - put it into NOARCHIVELOG MODE;

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
SQL> STARTUP MOUNT;
SQL> ALTER DATABASE NOARCHIVELOG;
SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```

==============================================================
But if DB is important, then:

```
rman> backup archivelog all delete input;
```

And if your archive backup if full, then:

```
rman> delete noprompt obsolete;
```

P/s: backup setting is a broad topic, my suggestion is to save you temporarily!